# IPC First send() and recv() calls in C++ TCP takes longer

Tags: c++, ipc, send, tcp, recv

I am using IPC (Inter-process communication) to send data between two C++ programs. For the IPC I use the basic TCP/IP Winsock2 code.

Basically the idea is that I send 3D data frames between the two applications, one processes the data using GPU/CUDA and the other displays it using a 3de party library (PCL). My applications are very rich in data (ie 30fps, 4Mb per frame), but that should not be a problem for IPC as far as I know.

So as each frame is finished processing on the GPU, I convert the frames data (X,Y,Z coords of type float; R,G,B of type uint8_t each) to bytes and send them one after the other.

Doing this I have noticed something odd. In my code I have 9 send() commands one after the other.

- 1ste : Sending a single char that acts as the name of the frame.
- 2de : A single int with the amount of 3D points incoming.
- 3-5th : RGB values
- 6-8th : XYZ values
- 9th : End of comms check to close the viewer application.

This whole process takes ~30ms to complete. What I found odd was where most of the time went. After timing each event I got the following:

- 1ste : 20ms (1 byte data)
- 2de : <1ms  (4 bytes data)
- 3-5 : 2ms   (921600 bytes of data)
- 6-8 : 3ms   (3686400 bytes of data)
- 9th : 1ms   (1 byte data)

Why is it that for the first send command it takes such a long time to complete, even when its only 1 byte of data, and then the rest of the data completes in record time. In between each time this loop runs, there is about a 20ms time delay waiting for the GPU code to finish. Does the TCP connection go into a sleep state, and if so can I disable it somehow.

TCP Socket code:

```
SOCKET Create_Server_Socket(PCSTR IP, PCSTR port)
{
struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
int iResult;

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

SOCKET ClientSocket;

ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

return (ClientSocket);
```

}

Code in question:

```
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)&name, sizeof(char), 0);  //Takes >20ms to complete
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)&points, 4, 0);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)Red_t, sizeof(uint8_t) * depth_width *depth_height, 0);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)Green_t, sizeof(uint8_t) * depth_width *depth_height, 0);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)Blue_t, sizeof(uint8_t) * depth_width *depth_height, 0);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)z_t, sizeof(uint16_t) * depth_width *depth_height, 0);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)x_t, sizeof(float) * depth_width *depth_height, 0)
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)y_t, sizeof(float) * depth_width *depth_height, 0);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, "a", sizeof(char), 0);
```

I am working on Windows 10 (ie the Winsock2 lib).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want "fast" IPC on Windows, why use sockets? Especially TCP which adds quite a lot of overhead (even when used locally). There must be some kind of in-memory shared structures that you could be able to use (perhaps just plain shared memory with a shared mutex for protection, and a couple shared signals of some kind to say when a packet from either side is ready).

Comment: I looked into Named Pipes but a lot of people said that their performance is about the same.. As far as I know if you use TCP locally it avoids most of the overhead.

Comment: Is there a reason for using so may send calls? As oppose to serializing the data (for example in a struct) and then use a single send call?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably suffering the penalty of "Nagle's Algorithm"
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Long story short, there is a delay built-in to TCP/IP with the purpose of collecting enough data to be worth sending a packet before the first packet is sent.  There is a TCP_NODELAY option that you can use when opening the socket to disable this, if it is a problem for you.

That having been said, if performance is of crucial importance, you might be better off using shared memory for inter-process communication rather than sockets.

Comment: Any thoughts on how TCP_NODELAY reacts with so may calls to send?

Comment: As far as I know, it will simply not delay your first few tiny packets until enough data have accumulated to be worth sending.  So, your "TTFB" (time-to-first-byte) will be shortened.  However, the time-to-last-byte will not be affected, so if you will always send all that data, and if the other side does not have anything to do until all the data have arrived, then it won't really matter.  As a matter of fact, it may result in slightly worse performance, because more packets will be exchanged, and each packet has a little overhead.